# Android app - app works but is very sluggish

Tags: android, performance, progress-bar

this is my first official and finished app...or so i thought...here are some of my issues (i will post code too):

1. when loading the app, it takes about 3 - 6 seconds for the ui to even come up...all it shows is the title
2. i have a progressbar view that i make visible while loading the next picture... that never gets made visible.
3. when you click on the next or previous buttons, the button stays pressed until it loads

These issues are driving me nuts...who can point me in the right direction

Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget210"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Medium Text "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="#88ffffff"
            android:background="#88000000" android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget214"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/widget215"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Previous"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Previous" 
                android:onClick="GetPrevPic"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:text="Next" 
                android:onClick="GetNextPic"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
package com.ndai.funnys;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import com.google.ads.*;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


public class GuysFunnysActivity extends Activity 
{
    String xml;
    Document doc;
    NodeList nodes;
    int iIndex = 0;
    int iTotal = 0;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GetXMLStuff();
        GetPic();
        CheckForUpdates();
        CheckForReferral();
    }
    public void GetXMLStuff()
    {
        xml = XMLfunctions.getXML();
        doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(xml);
        nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        iTotal = nodes.getLength();
    }
    public void CheckForReferral()
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GuysFunnys", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        long loads = settings.getLong("Loads", 0);
        if (loads % 50 == 0)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Thank you for using Guy's Funnys. Our app is only know to those who use it (it isn't in the Play Store). Please send a link for it to your friends. Send link now?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                    {
                        Intent ii=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        ii.setType("text/plain");
                        ii.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share Guy's Funnys App");
                        ii.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I wanted to share this cool app with you - Guy's Funnys - https://sites.google.com/site/guysfunnysapp/Guys%20Funnys.apk");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ii, "Share Guy's Funnys App"));
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                    {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        editor.putLong("Loads",(loads + 1));
        editor.commit();
    }
    public void CheckForUpdates()
    {
        PackageInfo pInfo;
        try 
        {
            pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            int s = pInfo.versionCode;
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://sites.google.com/site/guysfunnysapp/appversion.txt");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            if (Long.valueOf(line) > s)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("A new verison of Guy's Funnys is ready to download. The older verisons will not work. Download Now?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                        {
                            Update("https://sites.google.com/site/guysfunnysapp/Guys%20Funnys.apk");
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        } 
        catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void Update(String apkurl)
    {
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(apkurl);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();
            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();
            File outputFile = new File(file, "app.apk");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) 
            {
                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(intent);  
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }  
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        menu.add(1, 1, 0, "View Page").setIcon(R.drawable.pageico);
        menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Share Pic").setIcon(R.drawable.shareico);
        menu.add(1, 3, 2, "Share App").setIcon(R.drawable.shareico);
        menu.add(1, 4, 2, "Exit").setIcon(R.drawable.exitico);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Element e = (Element)nodes.item(iIndex);
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case 1:
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "link")));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
                return true;
            case 2:
                Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Guy's Funnys");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "guid"));
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Guy's Funnys"));
                return true;
            case 3:
                Intent ii=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                ii.setType("text/plain");
                ii.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share Guy's Funnys App");
                ii.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I wanted to share this cool app with you - Guy's Funnys - https://sites.google.com/site/guysfunnysapp/Guys%20Funnys.apk");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ii, "Share Guy's Funnys App"));
                return true;
            case 4:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void GetNextPic(View view)
    {
        iIndex++;
        if (iIndex == iTotal)
        {
            iIndex--;
            Toast.makeText(this, "At last photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
        else
        {
            GetPic();
            AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }
    public void GetPrevPic(View view)
    {
        iIndex--;
        if (iIndex == -1)
        {
            iIndex++;
            Toast.makeText(this, "At first photo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }
        else
        {
            GetPic();
            AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        }
    }
    public void ShowDebug(View v)
    {
    }   
    public void GetPic()
    {
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ImageView imgView =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        TextView txtView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (iTotal==0)
        {
            txtView.setText("Network Error");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error connecting to server. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(iIndex);
            txtView.setText(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "title"));
            Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "guid"));
            imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exc="+e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are making network connections, ex: checkForUpdates(), on the main UI Thread.  Making network connections should be done with the help of a background Thread.  AsyncTask will make this easier for you.  Right now, as it is, you are tying up your UI Thread which is creating "lag" issues with your UI.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: i tried to use threads...it was the same lag...but let me find a few tutorials and see what i see...i am an ASP.Net programmer gone rouge...so i am learning

Comment: i have moved the getpic to an AsyncTask...but now it is makeing the ui all funky and it eventually crashes

Comment: @GuyCothal You'll have to manipulate the UI in ``onPostExecute()``. :-)